# SmartGWT: Getting custom widget from VLStack

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hi I have defined a custom widget:
public class BookingArea extends Composite
{
...
}
which contains some smartgwt widgets.

From my entrypoint class I add x amount of this widgets inside a VStack.
I now want to remove some of the widgets from VStack as something like this:

Canvas members[] = vStack.getMembers();

for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++) { 
//Here I want to check for example, a member of the BookingArea widget,
//how do I convert one canvas to BookingArea?

}

Please help me I cant figure this out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=278